# Why does this code run when using Visual Studio Code's Java debugger extension while simultaneously generating errors when compiling with javac?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, javac

While writing a program, I was running the code using [VSCode's Java debugger extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-debug), which was working well. However, I realized that even though the code seemed to be executing just fine within `VSCode`, it was unable to compile when using `javac` from my terminal.

Here is the code.

`Program.java`

```
abstract class AbstractClass<T> {
    public static <T, C extends AbstractClass<T>> C func(Class<C> cls) {
        C child = null;

        if (cls == Child.class) {
            child = (C) new Child();
        }

        return child;
    }
}

class Child<T> extends AbstractClass<T> {}

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child<Integer> child = AbstractClass.func(Child.class);

        System.out.println("Program works!");
    }
}
```

---

### Using `VSCode` to compile and run the program...

**VSCode:** `Run` > `Run Without Debugging`

**VSCode's terminal output:**

```
nick@Nick-PC:~$  /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/bin/java --enable-preview -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp /tmp/vscodesws_f9a6f/jdt_ws/jdt.ls-java-project/bin Program 
Program works!
```

---

### Using `javac` and `java` to compile and run the program...

**Terminal:** `javac ./Program.java && java ./Program`

**Terminal output:**

```
Program.java:5: error: incomparable types: Class<C> and Class<Child>
        if (cls == Child.class) {
                ^
  where C,T are type-variables:
    C extends AbstractClass<T> declared in method <T,C>func(Class<C>)
    T extends Object declared in method <T,C>func(Class<C>)
Note: Program.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

---

Adding a break-point to the line that is generating compilation errors (line #5) and running with debugging through `VSCode` shows that the line considered buggy by `javac` is indeed executed.

I've tested this issue with fresh installs of both `VSCode` and `openjdk`, and the results remained the same.

The extension seems to be running a `Program.class` file located at `/tmp/vscodesws_f9a6f/jdt_ws/jdt.ls-java-project/bin` but wouldn't that file have to generated through compilation? Attempting to run the code after deleting this class file will cause it to be re-created.

This issue is really confusing me, as running the program using the extension would still require the code to be compiled prior to execution, right? How does the extension compile the code if it contains compilation errors? Am I misunderstanding how the Java debugger extension works?

---

**How is it possible that `VSCode`'s Java debugger extension is able to run this code at the same time that `javac` fails to compile it?**

Comment: Not all compilers are created equal. Most probably VSCode uses some own compiler (not `javac`) which functions slightly differently than `javac`. It is quite common that IDEs use their own compilers, not `javac` (this is definitely the case with Eclipse).

Comment: Indeed, it is common for IDEs to use a compiler suited for incremental compilation. Still... this would indicate the compiler is breaking from the language spec which should be considered a bug IMO. In any case, you probably want to use the isAssignableFrom() method in Class.

Comment: @Gimby the Eclipse Compiler even lets you compile & run code which has Syntax-Errors, as long as you don't hit the errornous parts